# Something wrong with iphone coded button

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview, uibutton

well, i'm making an app from a UiWebView example i found. and i needed to add a button but the way this example works is similar to phonegap so i figured out i need to add the button as a subview to the window, so then i got my button and set it up for pressing but when ever i press it my app crashes... can any one help? here is my code snippet:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    myLoadingLabel.hidden = YES;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [window addSubview:webView];
//my button
    UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(122, 394, 76, 76);
    [playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mic.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mic.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [window addSubview:playButton];
}

-(void)playAction {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
}
```

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebView_ExampleAppDelegate playAction:]:`

oh and i know its a long shot, but i need this button outside of the webpage because it needs to start recording audio when clicked, then when clicked again it needs to stop recording and save, run a command with system();, and then put the data gotten from the system command into the uiwebview to be used... so yea if anyone knows some code i would appreciate it greatly, and its a jailbreak app so the system command will be ok. Thanks!!!

Comment: @KevinBallard this is my error, `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebView_ExampleAppDelegate playAction:]: `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking a method named `playAction:` but you implement a method named `playAction`. Mind the missing colon. The crash most likely is related to that issue.

For a quick fix, change

```
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: those two strings are exactly the same

Comment: Look again - you missed the collon

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
@selector(playAction:)
```

vs.

```
- (void)playAction
```

The former refers to a method called `-playAction:` that takes one parameter, but you’ve implemented a method called `-playAction` that takes no parameters. Drop the colon from the `@selector` block and it should work.